# Could not find windows runtime type windows.UI.Xaml.Tickbar

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

After running my program on my device I get the error Could not find windows runtime type windows.UI.Xaml.Tickbar in my xaml.

I have overlooked the Xaml many times but I can't see any error in it I hope the people from Stackoverflow can help me

The piece of xaml where the error is in:

```
  <DataTemplate>
                    <ScrollViewer Height="543" Margin="0,0,-0.167,0" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Auto" >
                        <Grid Height="708" Name="ProfileContent">
                            <Image x:Name="ProfileImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="149" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="143" Source="{Binding image}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                            <Button x:Name="BtnChangePic" Content="Change" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="175,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="BtnChangePic_Click" Width="156" x:Uid="BtnChangePic"/>
                            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="109,180,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding name, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="TBlockName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,195,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" x:Uid="TBlockName" Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20"/>
                            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="109,224,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding location[4], Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222" Height="39"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="TBlockLand" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,245,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Land" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" x:Uid="TBlockLand"/>
                            <Button x:Name="BtnImgDel" Content="Delete" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="175,62,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="BtnImgDel_Click" Width="156" x:Uid="BtnImgDel"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Seo_name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="289,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding seo_name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="0"/>
                            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="109,268,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding location[3], Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222" Height="39"/>
                            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="109,312,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding location[2], Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222" Height="39"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="TBlockProvincie" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,289,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Provincie" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" x:Uid="TBlockProvincie"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="TBlockCity" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,327,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Stad" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" x:Uid="TBlockCity"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="TBlockStreet" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,371,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Straat" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" x:Uid="TBlockStreet"/>
                            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="109,356,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding location[1], Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222" Height="39"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="TBlockHouseNumber" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,400,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Huisnummer" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" Width="94"/>
                            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="109,400,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding location[0], Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222" Height="39" x:Uid="TBlockHouseNumber"/>
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,459,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Telefoon" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20"/>
                            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="109,444,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding phone, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222" Height="39"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="TBlockHide" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,500,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Verbergen" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" x:Uid="TBlockHide"/>
                            <CheckBox Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="116,484,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="55" IsChecked="{Binding hidephone, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <Button x:Name="BtnSaveProfile" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,551,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="321"/>

                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </DataTemplate>
```

Thank you

Comment: Your code snippet does not contain any `Tickbar` element. Are you using it somewhere outside of this code?

Comment: I can't remember ever touching the Tickbar element I can't even find it for wp8.1. At the moment it just gives the error invalid Xaml

Comment: Does the error disappear when you remove all child items from the `Grid`? If yes, add them back one by one and tell us when the exception reappears.

Comment: I think I found the issue it was in the x:Uid elements for some reason I'm going to try to re add them all. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let us know if that's going to be the solution. I suggest posting an answer to your own question, so that this post won't get bumped by the system as an unanswered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error in my Xaml after deleting all the X:Uid codes the problems was fixed.

Thank you Physikbuddha for helping